# SharePoint Access Requests - default to Visitor / Read or custom group

Tags: 2013, groups, access

For SharePoint `Access Requests`, how can we default the requested permission to Visitor/Read-Only or (preferably) a custom group? They seem to default to `Contribute` for us:

[image]

By "forcing" the access request to a custom group (or read-only) this would make it much easier for our users to bulk-manage the permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a group as a default group of the site. Doing this would make the group appear by default when a user requests permissions to the site. If you go to Group Settings, there is an option to set Group as default.

You can also change the permission you give to a user by clicking on the ellipsis shown next to the user.

Source: http://sharepointmadam.blogspot.in/2014/08/failed-to-decline-request.html